# Passing a string from a javascript file to search in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, database, mongodb

I am creating a website that uses get values from checkboxes in the javascript file (jQuery), filter.js and places the values in the String resultString.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").click(function() {
    var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (result.length > 0) {
      var resultString = "";
      result.each(function(){
        resultString += $(this).val() + " ";
      });
      alert(resultString);
    } else{
      alert("No checkbox checked");
    }
  });
```

I am trying to then bring this `resultString` to my index.js file to search the String through my MongoDB database through full text searching. I currently have the search method working and searching for the term "chicken" as seen but I want my resultString to be here instead

```
router.get('/recipe', function(req, res, next) {
  Recipe.find({ 
    $text: { $search: "chicken" } 
  }, { 
    score: { $meta: "textScore"}
  },  function(err, recipe) {       
    res.json(recipe);
  }).sort({
    score: { $meta: "textScore" }
  });
});
```

I'm just wondering if anyone can help with my problem. Ask any questions if not clear thanks.

Comment: Replace `alert(resultString)` with an Ajax request that sends the `resultString` to `YOURDOMAIN/recipe`. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Are you asking how to send a client side value, ie `resultString`, to the server side in order to be processed? If so, AJAX is your answer. Also, `map()` and `join()` is a more succinct method of building your resultString.

Comment: Yes, so I want to send my resultString in the js to where the search term "chicken" is in my index.js to send to mongoDB. Thanks for the Ajax hint,  would you have any idea how To start this function as I have little Ajax practise?